# Octave contourc format -> point coordinates

Tags: plot, octave

octave saves the data of a contour in the contourc format which is a little bit special for me.

Is there some function or script which translates these data into a sequence of
point  coordinates which I can plot then? For one level only!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example to process contourc format for one level (with potentially more than one contours at that level).

```matlab
A = zeros(5); A(2:4,2:4) = 1; A(3,3) = 0; % example image
ContourCFormat = contourc(A, 1); % one level only (but here happens to have two contours)
C = cell();
while ~isempty(ContourCFormat)
  N = ContourCFormat(2,1);
  C{end+1} = ContourCFormat(:, 2 : 1+N); 
  ContourCFormat(:, 1 : 1+N) = []; % Remove processed points
end
```

```matlab
C =
{
  [1,1] =

     1.5000   2.0000   3.0000   4.0000   4.5000   4.5000   4.5000   4.0000   3.0000   2.0000   1.5000   1.5000   1.5000
     2.0000   1.5000   1.5000   1.5000   2.0000   3.0000   4.0000   4.5000   4.5000   4.5000   4.0000   3.0000   2.0000

  [1,2] =

     2.5000   3.0000   3.5000   3.0000   2.5000
     3.0000   2.5000   3.0000   3.5000   3.0000

}
```

---

**Explanation:** From the [octave manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Two_002dDimensional-Plots.html#XREFcontourc):

> The return value is a 2xn matrix containing the contour lines in the following format:
>
> ```matlab
> [lev1, x1, x2, …, levn, x1, x2, ...
>  len1, y1, y2, …, lenn, y1, y2, …]
> ```
>
> in which contour line n has a level (height) of `levn` and length of `lenn`.

Therefore for the first contour, we collect columns from 2 to N+1, where N is given by element (2,1) of the contourc output. Then we delete N+1 elements and process the next contour in the same way, until there are no more points left.

Comment: for the sake of performance, you might want to have an `offset` variable that you increase with `N` each iteration thus saving you from having to remove processed points and reducing copying. If you do that, there will be no copy at all since each array in the cell array will be just a reference to `ContourCFormat`

Comment: Hi @carandraug! Tbh, I was going more for simplicity / readability than performance, but it's a good point, thanks! :p